# R replace values of a column based on exact match of another data frame

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames in R

`DF1` is

```
ColA ColB  observation
123  Text1 45
234  Text2 65
345  Text3 78
```

`DF2` is

```
ColumnA ColumnB metric
123     Text1    7
123     Text2    65
345     Text1    102
```

I want to replace the `observation` column of `DF1` with values of the `metric` column of `DF2` but only for the rows that have an exact match on `ColA`=`ColumnA` and `ColB`=`ColumnB`. The above example shall output the following data frame:

```
ColA ColB  value
123  Text1 7
234  Text2 65
345  Text3 78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, using `merge` + `ifelse`

```
DF <- within(merge(DF1,DF2,by.x = c("ColA","ColB"),by.y = c("ColumnA","ColumnB"),all.x = TRUE),
             value <- ifelse(is.na(metric),observation,metric))[-(3:4)]
```

such that

```
> DF
  ColA  ColB value
1  123 Text1     7
2  234 Text2    65
3  345 Text3    78
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `dplyr`:

Since you did not provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) I could not test the code...

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, by=("ColA"="ColumnA", "ColB"="ColumnB") %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(!is.na(metric), metric, observation)
```